# Python Regex - Select Text between a pattern

Tags: python, regex

Have below sample text descriptions

Input
Example 1: (Have Comments in the text)

**1. ADEQUATE HANDWASHING SINKS PROPERLY SUPPLIED AND ACCESSIBLE - Comments: AN HANDWASHING SINK INSTALLED AT  EAST BAR AREA.NEED TO RELOCATE HANDWASHING SINK AT MIDDLE OF AREA  BEHIND THE BAR COUNTER FOR  ACCESSIBILITY TO HAND WASHING.  PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION :7-38-030(C), NO CITATION ISSUED**.

Example 2: (No Comments in the text)

**47. FOOD & NON-FOOD CONTACT SURFACES CLEANABLE, PROPERLY DESIGNED, CONSTRUCTED & USED**

The Output should be like below. Need to extract all texts after starting index numbers,followed by '.' and before '- Comments:'. If no '- Comments:' found then extract all texts after the starting index numbers.

**ADEQUATE HANDWASHING SINKS PROPERLY SUPPLIED AND ACCESSIBLE**

**FOOD & NON-FOOD CONTACT SURFACES CLEANABLE, PROPERLY DESIGNED, CONSTRUCTED & USED**

Tried using the regular expression `'(?:^[\d+. ]*)(.*?)(?:\-\s\w*: ?)'`  which worked for example 1 but not for example 2.

Is it possible to match both examples in one regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one regex find all approach.  We can match on the following regex:

```regex
\d+\. (.*?)(?: - |\r?\n|$)
```

This will match from the start of a numbered section until reaching either `-`, CR?LF, or the end of the input.

```py
inp = """1. ADEQUATE HANDWASHING SINKS PROPERLY SUPPLIED AND ACCESSIBLE - Comments: AN HANDWASHING SINK INSTALLED AT EAST BAR AREA.NEED TO RELOCATE HANDWASHING SINK AT MIDDLE OF AREA BEHIND THE BAR COUNTER FOR ACCESSIBILITY TO HAND WASHING. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION :7-38-030(C), NO CITATION ISSUED.

Example 2: (No Comments in the text)

47. FOOD & NON-FOOD CONTACT SURFACES CLEANABLE, PROPERLY DESIGNED, CONSTRUCTED & USED"""

matches = re.findall(r'\d+\. (.*?)(?: - |\r?\n|$)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['ADEQUATE HANDWASHING SINKS PROPERLY SUPPLIED AND ACCESSIBLE',
 'FOOD & NON-FOOD CONTACT SURFACES CLEANABLE, PROPERLY DESIGNED, CONSTRUCTED & USED']
```